# Sinusoidal form for $\tan^{-1}(\sin x)$

Tags: trigonometry

This is a quick question, hopefully I'm missing something really obvious. So I've long been aware of [these identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions), which we get by composing an inverse trig function $g(x)$ inside of a standard trig function $f(x)$ to get $f(g(x))$, and algebraic expression in terms of $x$. However, I have been wondering if there is a synonymous form for $g(f(x))$, specifically $\tan^{-1}(\sin x)$. Looking at the function on Wolfram Alpha I noticed the similarities to the function $\frac{\pi \sin x}{4}$, although they are not synonymous. I include a graph for comparison. WA also tells me that my scaled $\sin$ function is equal to $\frac{1}{8} i \pi e^{-i x}-\frac{1}{8} i \pi e^{i x}$, and also that the composed function is equal to $\frac{1}{2} i \log[1+\frac{1}{2} (e^{-i x}-e^{i x})]-\frac{1}{2} i \log[1+\frac{1}{2} (e^{i x}-e^{-i x})]$
$= \frac{1}{2} i [\log(1-i \sin(x))-\log(1+i \sin(x))]$. I unfortunately don't see any immediate similarity between these two expansions, but I still wonder: *is there is an alternate form for $g(f(x))$ in terms of elementary or special functions, equivalent to the forms we get for $f(g(x))$?*
[image: graph comparison]

Comment: I find it interesting that the the scaled $\sin$ function is entirely constrained within the function composition

Comment: Actually any function $f$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$ wil give you a similar graph as $\tan x$, for an appropriate coefficient of $\sin x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid various factors $i$ I shall argue about hyperbolic functions. We then have
$$\sinh=P\circ\exp,\quad \tanh=Q\circ\exp\ ,$$
where $P$ and $Q$ denote certain simple polynomials (and similarly for the other basic hyperbolic functions).
It follows that, e.g., 
$$\tanh\circ\sinh^{-1}=Q\circ\exp\circ\exp^{-1}\circ \>P^{-1}=Q\circ P^{-1}\ .$$
Here the right hand side is a certain (hopefully simple) algebraic function of $x$. On the other hand, in
$$\tanh^{-1}\circ\sinh=\exp^{-1}\circ\> Q^{-1}\circ P\circ\exp$$
there is no such cancellation, nor do we have a formula that would simplify the $\log$ of the resulting algebraic expression in $e^x$.